# Unable to do delete operation through spring rest endpoints

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to create a crud application with spring as backend.I have created maaping for fetching,creating and deleting users.However the delet request is not working.The other two mapping work fine.

Here is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users,Long> {

    @Transactional
    void deleteByuserName(String username);
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @PostMapping(value = "/users/create")
    public Users postCustomer(@RequestBody Users user) {

        Users _user = usersRepository.save(new Users(user.getUserName(),user.getPassword(),user.getUserRole()));
        return _user;
    }


    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<Users> getAllReports()
    {
        return usersRepository.findAll();
    }



    @DeleteMapping(value = "/users/delete/{userName}")
    public @ResponseBody void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable("userName") String userName) {
        System.out.println("Delete User with name = " + userName + "...");

        usersRepository.deleteByuserName(userName);
    }

}
```

The error I get in postman is:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-04-12T09:18:51.401+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/users/delete"
}
```

Comment: I suspect it must be `deleteByUserName` not `deleteByuserName`?

Comment: May be your method name has to be "deleteByUserName"  U caps

Comment: made the changes that you guys told,still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong on this but I would expect the error in postman to be  "path": "/users/delete/user"? Are you sure you're passing the username for the path variable?

Does the request ever enter the controller and print your message:

System.out.println("Delete User with name = " + userName + "...");

?

Comment: Nothing is printed on the screen.I'm passing the username through the param option of postman

Comment: You need to just pass it as part of the url in postman with the delete option selected e.g.  http://serveraddress:port/users/delete/john